# Comparing 2 javascript numeric values in IF condition

Tags: javascript

I set up a validation function in javascript to validate the values from the HTML page:

```
<script>
    function validate() {
        var tterr = document.sngo2a.ttime; //This variable captures the value in field ttime              
        var ttserr = document.sngo2a.sngottime; //This variable captures the value in field sngottime

        var errortimecheck = 0;
        if(ttserr.value > tterr.value)
        {
            errortimecheck = 1;
            var sentence31 = "ERROR!!   \n\nTravel time in Stop-&-Go cannot be greater than the \nTotal travel time"; 
            alert(sentence31);
            alert(ttserr.value);
            alert(tterr.value);
        }
        else
        {
            errortimecheck = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm getting the following values from the html page:

> ttime = 10
>   sngottime = 7

I then expected not to see any alert messages. However, I'm getting the alert message "ERROR!! Travel time in........."

To make things even more confusing, when I replaced sngottime from 7 to 1. The logic runs fine.

When displaying the values for tterr.value and ttserr.value, they seem to be displayed correctly.

Can anyone help me out in figuring out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption here that your `ttime` and `sngottime` are strings.

This means that JavaScript will evaluate them in Lexographic order (alphabetic order).

So, alphabetically, your evaluation will check the following:

1. Does 7 appear later than 10 alphabetically
2. It does, therefor go into your first block of code and present the `alert`

In the case of changing `sngottime` to 1:

1. Does 1 appear later than 10 alphabetically?
2. It doesn't! Go to the else part of your If statement

To remedy this, explicitly cast your values to `Integers` (or any other numeric type):

```
if(parseInt(ttserr.value) > parseInt(tterr.value))
{
    errortimecheck = 1;
    var sentence31 = "ERROR!!   \n\nTravel time in Stop-&-Go cannot be greater than the \nTotal travel time"; 
    alert(sentence31);
    alert(ttserr.value);
    alert(tterr.value);
}
else
{
    errortimecheck = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Yannick,It worked. Thank you so much :) I have another query. I had also written a following condition in my code: if(ttserr.value > 250) { alert(ERROR!!) }.  This piece of code is working fine whenever ttserr.value is greater than 250.               So i am wondering how the comparison between a string and numeric field got successful?      Thanks once again :)

Comment: If it was useful, consider voting it up. If you feel your question has been answered, consider accepting it. As per your question about inter type comparisons, an implicit conversion happens, because half of your evaluation contains a number, the other half is implicitly cast to a number as well, as per the ECMA spec.